# getting undefined method `_' for #<Puppet::Resource::Catalog::Compiler:0x00000003f03338>

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I am getting:

```
1) ntpd should contain class ntpd
 Failure/Error: is_expected.to contain_class('ntpd')

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `_' for 
 <Puppet::Resource::Catalog::Compiler:0x00000003f03338>
```

when I run the 'rake spec' command against a puppet unit test file.  The code in the unit test file is simple:

```
require 'spec_helper'
#require 'shared_contexts'

describe 'ntpd' do

# Pre resource tests

   it 'should contain class ntpd' do
      is_expected.to contain_class('ntpd') 
   end

end
```

About 18 months ago this code worked.  I downloaded all the required gems to run the 'rake spec' command recently as I am picking up the puppet unit testing project again and now all I can get is the above error.  I did a bunch of searching online but no one seems to have run into this specific error.  I only end up working with ruby when I work with puppet so my ruby skills are basic.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm where this error is actually occurring because the posted code will not produce this error. This error can be recreated in a primitive fashion as a method call like `"this"._` but you code does not show anything of this nature

Comment: It is conceivable that there is a mismatch between the version of Puppet spec_helper and the version of Puppet that it located and is trying to use.

Comment: Can you include your Gemfile in the post?

Comment: Don't worry about the Gemfile. This is broken for me too on latest Puppet 3, and I suspect it's broken for everyone. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging I finally found the answer.  As a part of the gems I installed to do the unit testing additional gems were installed by several of those gems.  The rspec-puppet-utils gem installed the puppet 5 gem.  We are still using puppet 3.8.  Once I uninstalled the puppet 5 gem the error disappeared and the unit tests started working.

Comment: Great. And me getting the same issue on Puppet 3 was a really weird coincidence.